# mySQL server and Java application

Tags: java, mysql, networking

Ok, so I am a little bit stuck with this problem and could really use some guidance...I have a java application that I have written in Java on eclipse and I also have a database created in mySQL on the same computer, now say I want to copy my java application to another computer on a different network but connect to that same database on my original computer on mySQL, what modifications do I have to make so I can connect to my database on different networks and areas? any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated. Beginner in Java and Databases so please try to explain thoroughly.

Comment: [Here is tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/) and you just have to set address of host where your database is. Of course port 3306 must be opened.

Comment: Your question is too broad, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions on SO.

Comment: What do you use to access to your database? Pure JDBC or any persistence framework such as JPA?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto pure JDBC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use a pure JDBC application you simply need to set the JDBC URL to match with your requirements knowing that the format is something like:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]][?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]
```

So assuming that your hostname is `foo` and the port is `3306`, the first thing that you will have to do is to change the current JDBC URL of your application for something like `jdbc:mysql://foo:3306` (assuming that your host is accessible from the other computer and you configured your firewall to accept connections on the port of your database).

More info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

For the second part of the job to do (assuming that you have a static IP address), you will need to configure a `port forwarding rule` at your internet modem level such that any access to your public IP on a given port will be directly routed to the local IP address of your machine on the mysql port. Check the documentation of your modem to know how to do such thing. Here is more info about [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)

Comment: I can successfully connect to the database with the computer I created it on, my question is if i transfer my program to another computer on a different network are there any requirements or modifications I need to make so I can access the database on another network? or is my database already accesible on other networks already.

Comment: It depends on the networks and how they are connected to each other. In what kind of network do you have your client (here the application) and your server (here the database)?

Comment: say the server lies on my home network, and the client runs on my school network

Comment: And how they are connected to each other? via internet I guess?

Comment: like for example lets say I made a login form and the database is on my computer and I sent it to your computer for you to 'register' and make an account, how do I let you be able to connect to my database and enter your credentials, through the application

Comment: OK I modify my answer in consequence then

Comment: thank you, I'm a junior in highschool, help is greatly appreciated

Comment: answer modified please check the second part of it

Comment: @NathanMarotta : Add tag for networking as well.

Comment: @NathanMarotta you're welcome